# Make image and padding responsive bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Can someone help me make my image and the padding around it 
responsive? I tried making my padding `%` instead of `px` and I added the `img-fluid` class to my image. It works to a certain extent, but if I make my window too wide, my image gets off center:[image: Image becomes off center]

If the screen isnt as wide, the image works fine:

[image: Image is centered]

HTML:

```
  <div class="Aligner">
      <div class="Aligner-item">

  <div>
      <div class="card authenticationRequest" style="">
        <div class="card-header-img">
          <img class="card-img-top mainImage img-fluid" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/bc/be/e6/bcbee6931f71db0d1629355bd61fe8cd--wolves-mans.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>Hi</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>Its</p>
          <p>Me</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.Aligner-item {
  width: 50%;
}

.mainImage {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

.card-header-img {
  background-color: #cf0000;
  /* padding: 40px 20px 40px 20px; */
  padding: 10% 10% 10% 10%
}
```

Can someone help? Here's my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38370/

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried to add `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to your `.card-header-img` ? Btw you can get rid of you padding or set it as shorthand `padding: 10%;`

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve: if you keep the same padding in all the resolutions, your image will be cropped/stretched. if you just want to center the image, then add `text-align: center` to `.card-header-img`

Answer (score 2):

add margin:0px auto;

```
.card-header-img {
  background-color: #cf0000;
  padding: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

it works

Comment: hi - apologies, but the jsfiddle i posted has an older version of bootstrap (older than the one i am using). If I am using bootstrap v3, I still get the same issue (i updated my jsfiddle). Would you mind helping me again?

Comment: make .mainImage {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}